# Where can I find LCDF tools for Windows?

Tags: otftotfm

I am grateful for the LCDF tools for font conversion in LaTeX, that can be found at https://www.lcdf.org/type/
However for me the FTP that hosted the Windows binaries on http://w32tex.org/ is not available anymore.

Can anyone help be where to find Windows binaries of these tools?

Comment: I have them in miktex and texlive.  Or are you missing something?

Comment: Try http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/lcdf-typetools-w32.tar.xz

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, I did not realize they are part of MikTeX!

Comment: Thank you @SimonDispa, that helps me on a computer where I cannot manually update MikTeX!